# How can I run front end Javascript files with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I often times find myself wanting to run simple frontend javascript files with node for testing. however node does not understand document, and is not able to access elements in my html. Is there a way to add this functionality or otherwise run frontend js files?

Comment: What's wrong with a browser?

Comment: zombiejs is out there

Comment: There are a lot of non-Node tools for testing frontend files. `JSBin`, `JSFiddle` come to mind.

Comment: If you want to use the files in order to run tests, you should use test runners, such as karma.js. But it largely depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Im looking into zombiejs and karma.js now, but basically wanted a quick way to run the js files in terminal.

Comment: I can't understand why this question has had so many downvotes. I'm struggling to understand the browser context, the node context and the best way to unit test my JavaScript files. I think the downvotes come from people who already know the "correct" answer, but then how on earth can someone who is struggling to understand get some clarity if they're not allowed to ask the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In today's world, you pick an environment that contains the Javascript interpreter and then you can program, not only using what is built into the Javascript language, but also what other capabilities are built into that specific environment.  In your case, the browser environment is where things like `window` and `document` come from.  So, to program with those objects, you need a Javascript environment that supports those objects.  Those objects are not built into the Javascript language itself - they are part of the browser environment.

node.js is also a Javascript environment, but it comes with a different set of APIs that do not include `window` and `document`, but it does include all sorts of things that the browser environment does not include such as the modules for http, net, streams, fs, etc...

So, if you wanted to run code designed for a browser in node.js, you would have to get a browser simulator (a library that makes the browser-specific things available so you can run them in nodejs such as [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer)) - it uses the Chromium engine from Google to make browser functionality available from nodejs.  If what you're trying to do is to test web page Javascript, then it may be easiest to use a program specifically designed for testing web page Javascript from nodejs such as [Mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This is a helpful answer, but as I mentioned in my comment above, it comes from such a lofty place of superior knowledge that it discourages people who are struggling from asking an innocent question. So, the sentence "It just doesn't so expecting it to...errant expectation" seems like you're talking down to the reader. If you just delete that sentence, the rest of what you wrote shines through as a really helpful answer.

Comment: @DavidHyogo - I reworked the answer per your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

No way, just like js code in different Browsers have different represents.