# Expose Javascript method to Web API

Tags: javascript

I want to expose a javascript method to API. How it can be done? Since JS is client-side and can only run with the browser. Is there any way I can achieve this. I have tried using node js but a similar method is not provided by Node Maps API.

Google Maps Geometry library provides a containslocation javascript method that tells if provided lat&long values exist in GeoFence.

I want to use the containsLocation method in my web API code to check the coordinates exist in polygon or not.

***Link to Google Map official documentation:***

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation

Comment: Where is the code of your API ?

Comment: What you need is a method to check if point is inside polygon. That is not a Google invented code, that is simple math. You should find it online for the language of your API (it most likely already exists).

Comment: It is in c# but I can write it in any language. Basically I just want to access Javascript method from WebAPI call and send a response returned by the method.

Comment: I have found multiple solutions but the one provided by the GMaps builtin method gives the most accurate results. @DamirKasipovic

Comment: _“Basically I just want to access Javascript method from WebAPI call”_ - then you’d “basically ” need to set up a headless browser on your server. Or you try to reverse engineer the actual HTTP requests happening in the background, and see if you can make those from the server side as well. (Could be problematic, if that requires cookies, tokens or something the like, that would get generated/requested by the JS portion on the client.) All in all, this is probably going to get a lot more complex, then you so far imagined. (And therefor I am voting to close this as “Needs more focus.”)

Comment: Interesting topic actually, maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368149/how-can-i-run-front-end-javascript-files-with-node - I think you need tool that load/simulate web browser to achieve what you need. The above suggest Karma as tool for Node.js, in C# there should be some other tools.